# Convert Date String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to convert a date string to a DateTime object as follows

```
tmpdate = "27-Apr 14:53";
TheDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpdate, "DD-MMM HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I keep getting exceptions about the string not being a valid date time. I've tried adding in the year as well with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `dd-MMM HH:mm` - note lowercased `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

try with little d :

```
TheDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpdate, "dd-MMM HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string tmpdate = "27-Apr 14:53";
DateTime TheDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpdate, "dd-MMM HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```